# How to convert the String to expected date format in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the String 08082012, now i need to convert this into expected date format in js/jquery, for example the format is M/d/y. So result will be 08/08/2012.

Can you guys suggest me the possible ways to achieve?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what if the input is 11111? Good luck with that. My suggestion: be **a lot** more stringent about what the input can be, because you can't really sanely parse all of those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know, that it only can have these 4 different formats use substring.

```
date = "08082012";

if(date.length == 8)
{
       new_date = date.substring(0,2) + "/" +  date.substring(2,4) + "/" +  date.substring(4);
}

if(date.length == 7)
...
```